# Cygwin/MinTTY Failing to Update Terminal Output Properly

Tags: terminal, cygwin, mintty

After a recent re-install of Cygwin I've been experiencing some odd behavior -- in that terminal output from a running application is not showing up when written, but will suddenly pop into existence under certain conditions.

For my particular situation, I'm running a Django server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This should spit out several status messages to the terminal as the server spins up, and should also display server requests and replies (in addition to Python `print` statements).  None of these are showing up.

However, when I modify a file that is part of the Django app the server restarts automatically (as it should) and all the output suddenly appears for the previous session.

A previous install of Cygwin worked fine.

The only known difference I have is that the previous install using the Cygwin Python (in `/usr/bin`) while my new install uses the Windows Pyton (in `/cygdrive/c/Python27`).  This was done for MySQL data connectivity purposes.

An addition oddity, which may point to a larger issue, is that after I run the server Cygwin requires 2 clicks on the close button (top-right 'X') to close the terminal window.  The first click renders the terminal useless, but the window itself remains; a second click removes it from the screen.

Has anyone encountered a situation where Cygwin is not updating the terminal output, and located a handy fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is a combination of the different Python installations and Python's "flushing" behaviour.

Flushing refers to writing something from memory to file or screen. When a well-designed program is writing something to a screen, it will detect that and write ("flush") it to the screen immediately, so it can be seen immediately. However, if a program is writing to a file on disk, making lots of small writes to a file is much slower than making one big one, so it will "buffer" small writes until there's a chunk of them to flush to the file at once. This is what Python does.

The problem you're seeing is that Cygwin's Python understands that MinTTY is a terminal, and so flushes to it frequently, but Windows Python can't tell the difference between a MinTTY terminal and a file on disk. It assumes what it's writing to is a file, so it queues up writes and flushes them in batches (the app restarting will trigger this), rather than  flushing each message as it appears. If you waited long enough (at a guess, enough for 64kb worth of messages to be queued up), you'd see them all being written to screen at once, too.

There are two solutions: either find a way to work around your MySQL issues so you can use Cygwin Python, or use Windows Python from a Windows cmd shell, which would be correctly detected as a terminal, and thus produce the correct flushing behaviour.

You may also have some luck disabling Python's buffering behaviour. If you run Python with a `-u` option, or add `sys.stdout.flush()` after print statements, that will prevent Python buffering up messages, and cause it to flush them to screen immediately.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print (and presumably its duplicate, although I didn't check that).

Comment: Thank you me_and for the full description!  I'm using it out of the `cmd` prompt at the moment.  Hopefully my reason for "needing" the Windows version of Python is wrong and I can go back to the Cygwin version after checking on some things.